# How to update bundle.js for static index.html page during webpack-dev-server run?

Tags: webpack

I run this command:

`webpack-dev-server --content-base deployment/deployment --hot --inline`

This starts my website correctly.  Then I updated `randomFile.js` with bad syntax (inserted "abc") that should cause a lint error or failure of some kind.  When I save `randomFile.js` webpack reports "webpack: bundle is now valid" and shows the file I modified along with two other files (dunno why the other 2 are there).  Webpack also reports emitting "bundle.js" and "guid.hot-update.json".

The site does not update.

<strike>I checked the timestamp on</strike>

`deployment/deployment/js/bundle.js`

and it has not updated.

#### webpack.config.js (also have .dev and .prod versions which seem to be ignored by webpack-dev-server)

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/main.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'deployment/deployment/js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jpg/,
      loader: 'file'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
        'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    ]}, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: [
         'style?sourceMap',
         'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
         'resolve-url',
         'sass?sourceMap'
     ]
   },{
        loader:'babel-loader',
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                test: /\.js/
    }]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After learning webpack-dev-server does not update the original bundle.js I think I know where the problem comes from.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Site</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bundle.css" /> 

  <input type="hidden" id="myUrlConfigValueInput" value="http://localhost/FibReactHello2/js/bundle.js">
  <input type="hidden" id="myAPIUrlConfigValueInput" value="http://localhost/mySite/api/">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="appEntrypt"></div>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`ReactJS` has an entry pointe at `appEntrypt`.  There is a dependency here on bundle.js.  Because webpack-dev-server does not update this file (only the in memory file), my site never updates.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, webpack dev server doesn't actually update bundle.js. It packs in memory and serves files from memory. So your website will likely break with javascript errors, but you will not see changes on the file system. And you don't seem to have any linting configured, so no linting is being done.

Comment: @MadWombat - Ok.  So the timestamp on bundle.js doesn't matter.  The rest of my question still stands.

Comment: @MadWombat - Actually I think you pointed me at the problem.  I just need to know how to fix it.  See updated question.

Comment: There is some weirdness in your config. You require() the html-webpack-plugin, but don't actually insert it into the config. Do you have a static  index.html? You add webpack-hot-middleware/client to your entries, but you are not using the middleware, so I expect your site will not auto-reload. Does your site change if you reload manually?

Comment: never mind the first half of my comment, looks like you have a static html file

Comment: Do you see any of your react components actually displayed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106615/discussion-between-mad-wombat-and-p-brian-mackey).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some extensive discussion it seems that publicPath directive is causing webpack dev server to serve statically compiled bundle rather than the one generated in memory by the dev server. Changing publicPath to `/js/` fixes things:

#### webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'deployment/deployment/js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/js/'
  },
```

Comment: Might I suggest that you reconfigure your webpack for the dev server a bit. 'webpack-hot-middleware/client' entry only works if you are using middleware with something like express or koa server. I found that doing true hot reloading (that is re-rendering components without reloading the page itself) of react components is kinda hard to configure right. You can add `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/` to your entries and remove the hot reload, so your page gets reloaded on changes or I can post my own hot reload config that involves a simple express server.

Comment: Sadly the suggestion to use the new entry point did not work.  The program is using `'./src/main.js'` as the entry point.  I was able to remove hot-middleware/client.

Comment: Yes, you should keep src/main.js, since that is your main file entry point

Comment: Even with both webpack-dev-server and main.js entry points the screen still flickers.  FYI, I have `HtmlWebpackPlugin` listed as a dependency, but it is not being used.